# How to convert comma separated and double quoted words string to list/array of strings in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, java-8

I have the below input string:

```
"["role_A","role_B","role_C"]"
```

I want to convert it to a list/array of strings containing all values(role_A, role_B, role_C).

I've done using the below code:

```
  String allRoles = roles.replace("\"","").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").split(",");
```

Can anyone please suggest more cleaner or better way to do it using Java8!

Comment: roles.substring(2,roles.length()-2).split("\",\"") or roles.replaceAll("\\[\"|\"\\]", "").split("\",\"");

Answer (score 1):

Existing example and ones with replacing quotes can break if there are quotes in the strings themselves. You can use JSONArray to parse it and then convert to a list if needed

```
String x = "[\"role_A\",\"role_B\",\"role_C\"]";
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(x);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Object one : arr) {
    list.add((String)one);
}
System.out.println(list); //prints [role_A, role_B, role_C]
System.out.println(list.size()); //prints 3
```

`json.jar` can be found in the [Maven repo](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "[\"role_A\",\"role_B\",\"role_C\"]";
String[] res = s.split("\\[")[1].split(",");
for (String str : res) {
    str = str.replace("]", "").replace("\"", "");
}
```

Resulting array `res` is your desired array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
String[] arr = s.substring(2, s.length()-2).split("\",\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is using GSON or Jackson or any Json converter.
but if you want to do it in manually you can use regex to remove any symbols and split it by comma. But I suggest to use library instead, to make your life easier.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<String> list = mapper.readValue("[\"role_A\",\"role_B\"]",
                    mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class,
                    String.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this can be as:

```
List<String> roles = Stream.of(rolesStr.replaceAll("[\"\\[\\]]","").split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(roles);
```

output:

```
[role_A, role_B, role_C]
```